# Significato di “pocchio”

Tags: word-meaning, regional

In *Maledetti toscani* di Curzio Malaparte si legge, a proposito del piglio dei toscani:

> E schietta prosa, e antica, eran quei modi, quelle paroline: «la venga via! gnamo, grullo! la 'un faccia sguerguenze! l'abbassi il pocchio! la si sbottoni! la si tiri giù il bavero! la 'un s'arricci la bazza!»

E più avanti, parlando degli abitanti di Livorno:

> Gruppi di mozzi giocano a tamburello davanti alla Botte Ritta, o attorcigliano il pocchio sulla nuca rasata dei Quattro Mori, o ruzzano fra le gambe dei marinai seduti con le spalle al muro ...

Ci sarebbero altre espressioni su cui ho dubbi, ma che cos'è il “pocchio”? Nel primo brano l'uso è figurato e “abbassare il pocchio” sembrerebbe qualcosa di simile ad “abbassare la cresta”. Ma qual è il senso letterale di “pocchio”? Dal secondo passo e da vaghe tracce in rete, ipotizzo che sia qualcosa come una crocchia o un altro modo per raccogliere i capelli. Qualcuno ha qualche fonte precisa? (Il termine, forse perché prettamente dialettale, non compare in nessuno dei soliti dizionari: Treccani, Zingarelli, GDLI, ...)

Comment: Dovremmo aggiungere la tag "regional"?

Comment: Ho chiesto a un mio amico fiorentino ma, purtroppo, non conosce questo vocabolo.

Comment: Grazie mille, @Charo! Immagino che sia “regional”, ma è una delle cose che vorrei capire.

Comment: Ah, ecco, @DaG: appare in questo [Vocabolario pratese-italiano](https://iltirreno.gelocal.it/prato/cronaca/2014/02/22/news/vocabolario-pratese-italiano-lettera-p-1.8718848) con il significato di "crocchia di capelli", che ha senso nel contesto dei brani che hai riportato.

Comment: Infatti ho trovato nel libro *Fughe in prigione*, anche di  Curzio Malaparte: «[...] dai capelli pendenti sugli orecchi in bande ricciute e annodati in pocchio dietro la nuca, dal naso lungo e diritto, dalle labbra sanguigne e cattive [...]».

Comment: Giusto! E infatti Malaparte era nativo di Prato (anche se non lo erano i genitori). Vuoi scrivere una risposta segnalando quel vocabolario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In questo [Vocabolario pratese-italiano](https://iltirreno.gelocal.it/prato/cronaca/2014/02/22/news/vocabolario-pratese-italiano-lettera-p-1.8718848) si legge

> **Pocchio** 
>
> Crocchia di capelli

significato che ha senso nel contesto dei brani riportati nella domanda.

Infatti ho trovato nel libro *Fughe in prigione*, anche di  Curzio Malaparte,

> [...] dai capelli pendenti sugli orecchi in bande ricciute e annodati in pocchio dietro la nuca, dal naso lungo e diritto, dalle labbra sanguigne e cattive [...]

brano che sembra confermare il significato del termine sopra riportato.

E nelle note di Giorgio Pinotti al libro [*Kaputt*](https://books.google.es/books?id=_JvqDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT409&dq=pocchio+capelli&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwigp_iSjtf1AhVwgs4BHagqAUAQ6AF6BAgIEAE#v=onepage&q=pocchio%20capelli&f=false), sempre di Curzio Malaparte, che si possono leggere anche [qui](https://www.academia.edu/9601225/Curzio_Malaparte_Kaputt_a_cura_di_Giorgio_Pinotti), ho trovato:

> Abbiamo altresì conservato – in assenza di chiare indicazioni d’autore – tutte le oscillazioni grafiche (del tipo *incendi*/ *incendii*, *effluvii*/ *impervi*,  *se stessi*/ *sé stessi*, *sestesso*/ *sé stesso*,  *se stessa*/ *sé stessa*), la compagine dei corsivi e dei tondi, delle maiuscole e delle minuscole (introducendo minimi ritocchi in linea con il sistema malapartiano, in questo ambito piuttosto ben delineato), le citazioni (talora liberissime, come, in particolare, quelle da Proust), mentre abbiamo provveduto a sanare, non di rado con l’appoggio di C e G, le numerosissime corruttele; segnaliamo quidi seguito gli interventi degni di menzione (anche relativi alla punteggiatura):
>
>
> [...]
> con i capelli raccolti in pocchio a sommo del capo > con i capelli raccolti in crocchia a sommo del capo [G]

Comment: Grazie, ottima scoperta! (Si può forse aggiungere, per completezza, che C e G indicano le edizioni di *Kaputt*, rispettivamente, del 1944 e del 1948.)

Comment: Confermo, il pocchio è la crocchia, i capelli raccolti con uno chignon o come si dice in inglese “bun”